# How can I disable warning output in SCIP?

Tags: scip

How can I fix the warning:

```
WARNING: Original variable <x> not released when freeing SCIP problem <my_solver>.
```

which is spammed once per x.

Option 1: Disable output.

Ref: https://www.scipopt.org/doc/html/PARAMETERS.php
Verblevel=0 disables stdout, but not errors / warnings. How can I tell SCIP to be quiet?

Option 2: Fix alleged memory leak.

This happens even though I am apparently freeing the problem, variables, constraints, and expressions correctly. I can verify this by attempting to free them another time, and watching the program explode.

This answer: http://listserv.zib.de/pipermail/scip/2020-December/004161.html implies this happens when using transform operations, which I am not doing.

I've also verified that there are no memory leaks using valgrind, though it claims there is some memory "still reachable", that memory does not grow no matter how many problems I set up and solve.

Comment: If you compile with `NOBLKBUFMEM=true`, valgrind may show more memory leaks. This options disables the extra memory handling layer that is implemented by SCIP. With it, all memory is freed by SCIP anyway, even though it was actually dangling.

Comment: With SCIP 8, there is some extra code in var.c to help on debugging these kind of variable capture/release mismatches. Have a look at top of that file (also the section on technical improvements in SCIP in the release report).

Comment: Setting a message handler lets you control almost all output of SCIP. For error messages, there is an additional callback to be set, if I remember right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per suggestions by @stefan, the simplest way to disable warning output is to use:

```c
void SCIPsetMessagehdlrQuiet ( SCIP * scip, SCIP_Bool quiet )
```

Defined here (for 8.0): https://scipopt.org/doc/html/group__MessageOutputMethods.php#gadd04befbbea2ee42599ee26db33d52c9

Passing `true` did in fact disable those warnings.